# VBScript Division - Is auto Rounding the result to 2 decimal places

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to convert a decimal number to hex, the inbuilt Hex function is limited to 8 characters so I'm having to write my own function, however VBScript seems to be rounding the number to 2 decimal places.

So for example.

106681252129194 / 16 = 6667578258074.625

the problem is when I do it in VBScript this code

```
strResult = 106681252129194 / 16
```

the result is 6667578258074.63, which makes calculating the hex digit a slight issue.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do an integer divison and remainder operation. Be invited to check out my attempt at a number (double < 2^50) to ascii function:

```
Function ntoa( nNum, iBase )
  ntoa = "0"
  If nNum Then
     ntoa = Mid( "-", Sgn( nNum ) + 2 ) + ntoaPos( Abs( nNum ), iBase )
  End If
End Function
Function ntoaPos( nNum, iBase )
  If nNum >= 1 Then
     Dim nD : nD = Fix( nNum / iBase )
     Dim nM : nM = nNum - nD * iBase
     ntoaPos =   ntoaPos( nD, iBase ) _
               & Mid( "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV", 1 + nM, 1 )
  End If
End Function
```

Basic test code:

```
  Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
      "zero (default: long)",           0     _
    , "zero (Byte)"         , CByte(    0   ) _
    , "min_long"            , CLng( -2^31   ) _
    , "max_long"            , CLng(  2^31-1 ) _
    , "min_long - 1"        ,       -2^31-1   _
    , "max_long + 1"        ,        2^31     _
    , "max_ulong"           ,  4294967295     _
    , "big"                 ,        2^40     _
    , "bigger"              ,        2^45     _
    , "bigger-1"            ,        2^45-1   _
    , "bigger-11"           ,        2^45-11   _
    , "very big"            ,        2^50     _
                             )

  Dim nTest
  For nTest = 0 To UBound( aTests ) Step 2
      WScript.Echo "-----", nTest \ 2, aTests( nTest )
      Dim nVal : nVal = aTests( nTest + 1 )
      WScript.Echo "       Type:", TypeName( nVal ), VarType( nVal )
      WScript.Echo "      Value:", nVal
      WScript.Echo "     hexxed:", ntoa( nVal, 16 )
      WScript.Echo "     decced:", ntoa( nVal, 10 )
      WScript.Echo "      abced:", ntoa( nVal, 32 )
  Next
```

Output:

```
----- 0 zero (default: long)
       Type: Integer 2
      Value: 0
     hexxed: 0
     decced: 0
      abced: 0
----- 1 zero (Byte)
       Type: Byte 17
      Value: 0
     hexxed: 0
     decced: 0
      abced: 0
----- 2 min_long
       Type: Long 3
      Value: -2147483648
     hexxed: -80000000
     decced: -2147483648
      abced: -2000000
----- 3 max_long
       Type: Long 3
      Value: 2147483647
     hexxed: 7FFFFFFF
     decced: 2147483647
      abced: 1VVVVVV
----- 4 min_long - 1
       Type: Double 5
      Value: -2147483649
     hexxed: -80000001
     decced: -2147483649
      abced: -2000001
----- 5 max_long + 1
       Type: Double 5
      Value: 2147483648
     hexxed: 80000000
     decced: 2147483648
      abced: 2000000
----- 6 max_ulong
       Type: Double 5
      Value: 4294967295
     hexxed: FFFFFFFF
     decced: 4294967295
      abced: 3VVVVVV
----- 7 big
       Type: Double 5
      Value: 1099511627776
     hexxed: 10000000000
     decced: 1099511627776
      abced: 100000000
----- 8 bigger
       Type: Double 5
      Value: 35184372088832
     hexxed: 200000000000
     decced: 35184372088832
      abced: 1000000000
----- 9 bigger-1
       Type: Double 5
      Value: 35184372088831
     hexxed: 1FFFFFFFFFFF
     decced: 35184372088831
      abced: VVVVVVVVV
----- 10 bigger-11
       Type: Double 5
      Value: 35184372088821
     hexxed: 1FFFFFFFFFF5
     decced: 35184372088821
      abced: VVVVVVVVL
----- 11 very big
       Type: Double 5
      Value: 1,12589990684262E+15
     hexxed: 4000000000000
     decced: 1125899906842624
      abced: 10000000000
```

BTW - you can't use \:

```
>> a = 2 ^ 32
>> WScript.Echo a
>> b = a / 2
>> WScript.Echo b
>> c = a \ 2
>> WScript.Echo c
>>
4294967296
2147483648
Error Number:       6
Error Description:  Overflow
```

Comment: Instead of using Fix(x / y) you can use VBScript's integer division operator: x \ y.

Comment: Aside from Hex issue with OP, what would be the guideline for performing operations and not losing precision in VBS? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You're exceeding the precision offered by type `Double`, i.e. 8 bytes.

It isn't really that division auto-rounds things to 2 decimal places; it's just that your 3rd+ decimal places have nowhere to go and are therefore rounded out.

One solution is to use type `Decimal`, which offers 14 bytes of storage space.

```
Dim r As Decimal
r = 106681252129194) / 16 ' r = 6667578258074.625
```

Note: The above is for VB. In VBA and VBScript, the `Decimal` type is only accessible within a `Variant`. You can't directly declare a variable of type `Decimal`; you have to create a `Variant` and then make its subtype `Decimal` using the `CDec` function:

```
Dim r
r = CDec(106681252129194) / CDec(16) ' r = 6667578258074.625
```

It's still good to be cautious... `Decimal` will give you 28-29 significant figures, while `Double` gives you only 14-15. On the other hand, `Double` gives you the flexibility of a power of 10 between -324 and +308 as in the scientific notation, while with `Decimal` you're stuck with straight notation, no powers of 10.

Comment: VBScript doesn't support Decimals, even when stored in a variant.  The `CDec` function doesn't exist, and even if you get a Decimal (for instance, from a database through ADO), you have to convert it to Double in order to compare or manipulate it.

Comment: Thank you, will have a go with that in a bit.